# How to generate random numbers in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, random

I'm here to ask help for a program that I don't know how to resolve:

```py
from random import randint
rain=[]

x=randint(0,500)
y=randint(0,500)

r=2
l=[x,y,r]

for k in range(7):
    rain.append(l)
print(rain)
```

I just want my program to produce random numbers in the rain list but my code produces:

```py
 [[46, 117, 2],
  [46, 117, 2],
  [46, 117, 2],
  [46, 117, 2],
  [46, 117, 2],
  [46, 117, 2],
  [46, 117, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```py
from random import randint

rain = list()

r = 2

for k in range(7):
    x = randint(0, 500)
    y = randint(0, 500)
    rain.append([x, y, r])
print(rain)
```